# Sitecore fail open windows inside of desktop

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

6.0 rev.130111 (Update-3)
But i see very strange behavior inside desktop mode
For example I can open Content Editor or Media library,
but a lot of sub windows like publish site, edit layout etc opening with error "the requested document was not found". I see reqvested URL and inside sitecore structure it is exist.
It is very strange ? how I can fixed ?
can it be releted to some settings ?
I have found some issue in SDN http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/KnownIssues%20Recommended/DisableBrowserCaching%20setting%20issue.aspx but I have latest version.

Comment: Delete all cookies and browser cache, close your browser, reset your IIS and try again. What did you do or change just before this started to happen?

Comment: I doesn't help. I do not make some think special with sitecore core (nothing at all). Can it be related to some web config settings or external libraries ?

Comment: That might be possible. Did it ever work before? And if so, did you upgrade or install some other packages/modules after that?

Comment: I have find-out the answer. I had bad links to sitecore content item in core database that located in  <site> section in web config. Thanks Martijn.

Answer (score 0):

I have find-out the answer. I had bad links to sitecore content item in core database that located in   section in web config.